Why does NetBeans 22 say my Project Folder is "unloadable" and therefore cannot find projects?
My NetBeansProjects folder is on my c: drive
In previous versions (20 the last I used) it opened that folder to the last project I had worked with.
Now,  under Projects in the upper left pane, it reports NetBeansProject (unloadable) with no explanation or hint as to what is wrong.
I am running on latest version of Windows 10

Could be a malformed project file (pom.xml or build.xml). Can you build the project from console? And maybe (even though unlikely) deleting the cache might help.

Seems that this is a common problem with NetBeans since long (NetBeans 6). You upgrade to a newer version and all of a sudden NetBeans does not want to load your project. It proposes to fix but then it says it cannot. Any manipulation with maven outside NetBeans work. So what is the problem? Somebody should know.
